# PDO skip if statement

Tags: php, pdo

im going to insane here, why he jump to else and return false all the time.
i dont understand what im doing wrong.

```
try 
    {
        $query = 'SELECT userID, firstname, surname, email FROM jinx_users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
        $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        $stmt = null;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $stmt = null;
        $this->dbh->rollback();
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: ->fetch() would return a boolean false if there's no more records to fetch.e.g. the query didn't match ANYTHING. If it jumps there all the time, then your email/password aren't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement is not a valid statement. Apart from that the Try Catch should be used to check if the database can succesfully be called or params can be set etc. Inside a try/catch you want to avoid return true or false. So with that being said I think what you want is the following:

```
try {
     $query = 'SELECT userID, firstname, surname, email FROM jinx_users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
     $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
     $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {
     var_dump($e->getMessage();
     die();
}

if($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, i actualy did session_start(); $_SESSION['firstname'] = row['firstname']; i add true false at last to see what it return

Comment: That's doesn't relay my answer. :-) If the connection is able to fetch anything the function while return true. Incase of a database error it will dump the message and die.